# Serial port to COM port - no output found

Tags: serial-port, windows-subsystem-for-linux, dmesg, port

I am using Ubuntu WSL1 in Windows. I want to find my serial port which is currently connected on COM4 and I am running this command:
dmesg | grep tty, dmesg | egrep tty, setserial commands, but nothing works. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

In WSL 1, COM4 should be automatically mapped to `/dev/ttyS4` as far as I know. Since WSL 1 is just an API wrapper on top of the Windows kernel (like an inverse of Wine) there might not be any messages about it in `dmesg`.

So, try `ls -l /dev/ttyS*`, or `setserial -g /dev/ttyS*`. Note that the device name is case sensitive, so the `S` must be upper case.

On the other hand, WSL 2 apparently won't support regular serial ports at all, but up-to-date versions of it can support USB-serial converters.

Comment: /dev/ttyS4: Input/output error
Cannot get serial info: Inappropriate ioctl for device

it is showing me this by using this command "setserial -g /dev/ttyS*"

Comment: So apparently `/dev/ttyS4` at least *exists*. Perhaps you can use it in WSL 1, but any changes to its hardware settings (like what would be done with `setserial` on real Linux) need to be done using Windows tools? Does `stty -F /dev/ttyS4 -a` return any information?

Comment: @telcoM That's likely the case.  WSL1 tends to provide *read* access to hardware through the Windows APIs, but "set" operations are typically relegated to Windows itself.

Comment: issue resolved, it takes that port automatically.